# Env stopped working correctly after calling openDexFile function in JNI case

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface

I have application that encrypt classes.dex file in android apps for reverse protection. After decryption classes.dex dynamically loading from memory, but I've trouble with android 4.4 KitKat (api level 19). After launching encrypted apk on emulator (AVD from Android studio) it crashes.

Problem is in this piece of code:

```cpp
jint mCookie = mem_loadDex_dvm(env, (char *)szDexPath);
// error appears in line below
jclass DexFileClass = env->FindClass("dalvik/system/DexFile");
```

[line in github](https://github.com/woxihuannisja/Bangcle/blob/76f84a741bdfc25504992327c8addcf4f000e403/jni/packer.cpp#L836)

exactly if to jump in mem_loadDex_dvm function, problem appear after this line

```cpp
openDexFile(args, &pResult);
```

[line in github](https://github.com/woxihuannisja/Bangcle/blob/76f84a741bdfc25504992327c8addcf4f000e403/jni/packer.cpp#L213)

Error text:

```
W/dalvikvm: JNI WARNING: JNI function FindClass called with exception pending
W/dalvikvm:              in Lcom/storm/fengyue/Native;.attachBaseContext:(Landroid/content/Context;)V (FindClass)
W/dalvikvm: Pending exception is:
I/dalvikvm: java.lang.RuntimeException: unable to open in-memory DEX file
I/dalvikvm:     at com.storm.fengyue.Native.attachBaseContext(Native Method)
I/dalvikvm:     at com.storm.fengyue.StubApplication.attachBaseContext(StubApplication.java:105)
I/dalvikvm:     at android.app.Application.attach(Application.java:181)
I/dalvikvm:     at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:991)
I/dalvikvm:     at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:975)
I/dalvikvm:     at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:511)
I/dalvikvm:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4317)
I/dalvikvm:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135)
I/dalvikvm:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
I/dalvikvm:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
I/dalvikvm:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
I/dalvikvm:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
I/dalvikvm:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
I/dalvikvm:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
I/dalvikvm:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
I/dalvikvm:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
I/dalvikvm:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
I/dalvikvm: "main" prio=5 tid=1 NATIVE
I/dalvikvm:   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x9cd62bd8 self=0xb8d0e4a0
I/dalvikvm:   | sysTid=2388 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[fopen-error:2] handle=-1216544672
I/dalvikvm:   | state=R schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=16 stm=0 core=3
I/dalvikvm:   #00  pc 000bd4b6  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmDumpNativeStack(DebugOutputTarget const*, int)+86)
I/dalvikvm:   #01  pc 00098093  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmDumpThreadEx(DebugOutputTarget const*, Thread*, bool)+1155)
I/dalvikvm:   #02  pc 00098386  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmDumpThread(Thread*, bool)+86)
I/dalvikvm:   #03  pc 0004ce17  /system/lib/libdvm.so (ScopedCheck::checkThread(int)+455)
I/dalvikvm:   #04  pc 000601e5  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/dalvikvm:   #05  pc 00008a26  /data/data/home.blank/files/.jiagu/libdexload.so (mem_loadDex(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, char const*)+1334)
I/dalvikvm:   #06  pc 00009158  /data/data/home.blank/files/.jiagu/libdexload.so (native_attachBaseContext(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jobject*)+1096)
I/dalvikvm:   #07  pc 0002a0eb  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+79)
I/dalvikvm:     at com.storm.fengyue.Native.attachBaseContext(Native Method)
I/dalvikvm:     at com.storm.fengyue.StubApplication.attachBaseContext(StubApplication.java:105)
I/dalvikvm:     at android.app.Application.attach(Application.java:181)
I/dalvikvm:     at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:991)
I/dalvikvm:     at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:975)
I/dalvikvm:     at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:511)
I/dalvikvm:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4317)
I/dalvikvm:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135)
I/dalvikvm:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
I/dalvikvm:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
I/dalvikvm:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
I/dalvikvm:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
I/dalvikvm:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
I/dalvikvm:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
I/dalvikvm:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
I/dalvikvm:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
I/dalvikvm:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/dalvikvm: VM aborting
```

It's no depend of FindClass, other functions give same error (env->GetFieldID or env->SetFieldID).
Tried to display env hex value, it similar before and after problem line.
Checked that JNI is attached of current thread.

All code are in [github](https://github.com/woxihuannisja/Bangcle/blob/76f84a741bdfc25504992327c8addcf4f000e403/jni/packer.cpp#L213)

Comment: I see way too many lines of code that make calls to the JVM that utterly ignore the possibility of a failed call or an exception being thrown.  The entire wall of code seems to assume every call to the JVM `env` works as intended and doesn't throw any exceptions.  Once you get one failed call, or ignore one exception, you can get results similar to what you're seeing at any time.

Comment: @AndrewHenle you are right, it fixed by adding `env->ExceptionClear();` after problem line, thank you!